# Find a structure $M$ for a suitable language $L$ such that $M \not\models (\forall x)(\exists(y)[x<y \rightarrow x+1=y]$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

> This is a part of exercise $4$ page $38$ in ***A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic*** by ***Leary***

Find a structure $M$ for a suitable language $L$ such that $M \not\models (\forall x)(\exists(y)[x<y \rightarrow x+1=y]$

---

> My attempt :
>
> Let $L=[\{1,+,<\}$ be our suitable language where $1$ is a constant symbol , $<$ is a $2$-ary predicate , $+$ is a $2$-ary function . Define $M$ to be a structure whose universe , $A=\{6,7\}$ and $1^{M} = 6 ,\  <^M = \{(7,6)\} ,\ +^M=\{[(x,y),7]:x,y \in A\}$
>
> In other words , the function $+^M$ sends every pair $(x,y)$ in $A\times A$ into $7$.
>
> Let $s:Vars \rightarrow A=\{6,7\}$ be our assignment function where $Vars$ is the set of variables of $L$ and let   $s(x)=6 \ \& \ s(v)=7 \ \text{for every}\  v\ne x$
>
> Now , define $h(v)=\underline{s[x|a][y|b]}(v)$
>
> $\text{note that}:  \underline{s[x|a][y|b]} \text{ means the Terms assignment function}$
>
> So , $M\models (\forall x)(\exists y)(x<y \rightarrow x+1=y)[s] \equiv \text{for every $a\in A$ there is $b\in A$ s.t. }$ $
> $
>   $M\models (x+1=y)[h] \text{ whenever  } M\models (x<y)[h]    \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  (1)$
>
> Now , I calim that this condition $(1)$ fails when we consider our particular $s$ and $M$ and so we proved the required! to show this :
>
> for $a=7$
>
> notive that:
>
> 1- $M\models (x<y)[h] \text{ iff } [h(x),h(y)]\in <^M$. and we have , $[h(x),h(y)]=[a,b]=[7,b]\in <^M \text{ iff } b=6$
>
> 2- $M\models (x+1=y)[h] \text{ iff } h(x+1)=h(y) \text{ iff } +^M[h(x),h(1)]=h(y) \text{ iff } +^M(6,6)=b \text{ iff } b=7$
>
> So for $a=7 , \text{ there is no $b\in A$ s.t. }M\models (x+1=y)[h] \text{ whenever } M\models (x<y)[h]$
>
> So it's not true that , $\text{for every $a\in A$ there is $b\in A$ s.t. } M\models (x+1=y)[h] \text{ whenever  } M\models (x<y)[h]$
>
> Hence , $M\not\models (\forall x)(\exists y)(x<y \rightarrow x+1=y)[s] \boxtimes$

---

I wonder if my solution works . I also hope you can provide better structures which makes the gived formula false!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how friendly is that introduction?

Comment: @GitGud , I'm in chapter 1 , but I have read up to the half of chapter 2. I find it easy to follow the text , but one problem is that there is no way to check your solutions if you don't and an instructor ( like my case! ).

Comment: @GitGud *Very* friendly. See http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/TeachYourselfLogic9-2.pdf

Comment: @PeterSmith ,I decided to read it after I have read your Guide! it was very helpful to use this guide to have an idea about the text treat this subject :) thanx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exercise unfortunately contains a typo, though one which you might perhaps have spotted. Why?

Because whatever the domain, whatever the constant 1 denotes, and whatever function + denotes, $x + 1$ must have a value in the domain , given an assignment of a value to $x$. That's because *in standard first order logic, all functions are total*. Hence

$$ \forall x\exists y(x + 1 = y)$$

will be true in all models. So, a fortiori, whatever relation < is,

$$ \forall x\exists y[x < y \to x + 1 = y]$$

also has to be true in all models. OK?? So your attempt to describe a model in which it fails must be wrong!

Moral: Always, always, print out the online errata for any logic book, in this case http://www.geneseo.edu/~leary/errata.pdf

Comment: By the way, in case anyone gets the wrong idea from this isolated example, I should say that Leary's nice book is very accurately typeset and proof-read, certainly compared with the first printings of some books I could mention -- in particular those by one P*t*r Sm*th.

Comment: Could you please point out what is the error in my attempt ?

Comment: I had re-checked the solution several times, but I can't find the gap, I'm not sure if there is a gap after revising the proof step by step more than 5 times. any help please ?

Comment: @Element You proved, given $a=7$, that $b=6$ implies $b=7$. But this statement can be satisfied if $b=7$ (the antecedent does not matter if the consequent is true). Thus "So for $a=7$, there is no $b\in A$ s.t. $M\models (x+1=y)[h]$ whenever $M\models (x<y)[h]$" is a false statement, since we can take $b=7\in A$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro , Oh yeah! I thought that  I have proved that this is true only when $6=7$ as the first case require $b=6$ but the second require $b=7$ and forget to notice that I work with an IMPLICATION!!