# What are the necessary components to finding structures for a suitable language?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

### The Question (and its Answer)

We are given the following:

$$\sigma: (\forall x)(\exists y)[x < y \rightarrow x + 1 \neq y]$$

Now, in order to find the structure of a language that makes $\sigma$ true, we say the following:

We will work in $\mathcal{L}_{NT}$, and let:
$$ \mathfrak{} = (ℕ , 0 ,  , + ,  , < )$$

be the standard structure.

We will let $s$ be a variable assignment that will assign $v_i$ to number $i$. We can see that this makes $\sigma$ true.

### The Problem:

It seems a bit too simplistic to be true that the aforesaid answer is sufficient structure of a language specifications to make $\sigma$ true. It feels like there must me other moving parts involved as well, and I'm not sure what those would be. Any ideas?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA for instance, consider how in the following question the questioner's attempt for a proof is rather long and involves assigment variables etc. 

I'm unsure about the structuring from that perspective, and if you could shed some light on that, that would be great. As always, thank you for being super helpful.

The question I'm referring to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541876/find-a-structure-m-for-a-suitable-language-l-such-that-m-not-models-fora?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If we want to have a "fully formal" proof that $\mathfrak N \vDash \sigma$, we have to apply the clauses of the *satisfaction* definition [see Leary, **Def.1.7.4**, page 29]:

> $\mathfrak N \vDash \sigma \text {  iff for every  } n \in \mathbb N : \mathfrak N \vDash (∃v_2)[v_1 < v_2 → v_1+1 ≠ v_2][s(v_1 \mid n)]$,

where I've adopted the convention that $x$ is $v_1$ and $y$ is $v_2$.

This in turn implies:

> $$\mathfrak N \vDash (∃v_2)[v_1 < v_2 → v_1+1 ≠ v_2][s(v_1 \mid n)] \text {  iff for some  } m \in \mathbb N : \mathfrak N \vDash (v_1 < v_2 → v_1+1 ≠ v_2)[s'(v_2 \mid m)]$$

where $s'(v_2 \mid m)$ is a "variant" of $s(v_1 \mid n)$.

What does it mean? Having chosen $n \in \mathbb N$ whatever, can we always find a suitable $m$ such that:

> $(n < m → n+1 ≠ m)$

holds in $\mathbb N$?

The answer is: Yes. For $s(v_1)=n$ it is enough to choose $s'(v_2)=n+2$.

---

The variable assignment function [see Leary, **Def.1.7.1**, page 28] is a function that maps variables of the language to elements of the domain. Spercigfically, for the above question we have:

> $s: \text {Var} \to \mathbb N$.

The symbols $s(v_1 \mid n)$ [see **Def.1.7.2**] is simply: $s(v_1)=n$.

Comment: this might be very basic, but what does $[s(v_1 | n)]$ refer to?

Comment: Mine is "A Friendly Introduction" By Leary and Lars. On that note, I am going through the proof line by line and something that stands out to me is the $V - 2$ in the second implication block, where usually there was $v_2$. Is that intentional? And if so, how is that $V - 2$ derived? If you agree to change the $V - 2$ to $v_2$, the good news is, I wholly understand this formal proof! Using this same proof structure, we should be ready to work on the counterpart where we have to come up with a structure that falsifies the $\sigma$, right?